# how convert curl php to multi domain and Cookie

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I wrote a code in php language that receives and displays the json file through cookies.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/list',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Cookie: session=example'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);


echo "$response";
?>
```

How can I get the following code to receive several json files from different sites with different cookies and display them in one file?

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

$curlData = array(
  array(
    'url' => 'https://example.com/list',
    'cookie' => 'session=example'
  ),
  array(
    'url' => 'https://anotherdomain.com/list',
    'cookie' => 'session=another'
  ),
  // Add more domains and cookies as needed
);

$responses = array();

foreach ($curlData as $data) {
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $data['url'],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Cookie: ' . $data['cookie']
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  $responses[] = $response;
}

// Output the responses
foreach ($responses as $response) {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

you can also save the $curlData array to a file in json format